# Smarter build caches in docker for independent commands

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Suppose my Dockerfile looks like the following

```
FROM base
RUN A1
RUN A2
RUN B1
RUN B2
```

Where A1, A2, B1, B2 are commands such that A2 depends on successful execution of A1, B2 depends on successful execution of B1.

But A1 and A2 are independent of B1 and B2, which means that I'll get the same results if my Dockerfile were instead

```
FROM base
RUN B1
RUN B2
RUN A1
RUN A2
```

Now the issue I have is that suppose B2 and A2 are heavy operations, so I want to use [the build cache](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#build-cache) whenever possible. That is, **I don't want changes to command A1 to cause B2 to run again, and I don't want changes to command B1 to cause A2 (and perhaps even A1) to run again.**

But I'm in a bind, because if I use the first ordering of the commands then changes in A1 will cause B1 and B2 to be run again, and if I use the second ordering then any changes in B1 will cause A1 and A2 to be run again.

I can't think of any neat way to do what I'm looking for.

**The best solution I've been able to think of** to get what I want to achieve is to have two separate images

Dockerfile A:

```
FROM base
RUN A1
RUN A2
```

Dockerfile B:

```
FROM base
RUN B1
RUN B2
```

And then to use [multistage build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) to combine these, i.e. have a third final Dockerfile

```
FROM A:latest as builder
FROM B:latest
COPY --from=builder /files/made/by/commands/A1/and/A2
```

Which has the obvious downside that you have to manually figure out changes made by commands A1 and A2, i.e. to know which files to copy in the multistage build Dockerfile. This may be tricky since commands A1 and A2 may be installing binaries, changing configuration files, etc

Comment: @VonC I would love to have your revised answer

Comment: I have revised the answer.

Answer (score -1):

> Which has the obvious downside that you have to manually figure out changes made by commands A1 and A2.

Then you need a way to keep track what A:latest and B:latest are.
Rebuild A, then:

- if A:latest has changed (refers to a new SHA256), then yes, do the multistage build for B.
- if A has not changed, you can build B *not* from `base`, but from `A:latest`.
  If B itself has not changed it will be quick.

Comment: In the third file, you have to copy files over from A:latest, right? So you can't blindly copy, you need to be aware of which files to copy. A may be installing binaries which you need in your final docker image, you will have to figure those out and copy those. That's where the complication is.

Comment: Thanks for updating the answer. But don't we run into the same problem if A:latest has updated? That we need to figure out every single file A is changing in the system and to copy that over in the multistage build?

Comment: @PeeyushKushwaha multistage build applies best if you know what to copy. In you case, it works if what to copy are specific files or folder. If this is more complex than that, then multistage build is not a good fit.

Comment: I agree. This is why I mentioned the multistage build solution in my question along with the shortcoming that you have to "manually figure out changes made by commands A1 and A2", i.e. know which files to copy

Comment: I updated the question to clarify what I meant by "figure out changes". Sorry about the confusion if it wasn't clear.

Comment: @PeeyushKushwaha If possible, do a blind copy.